# Showing $\sqrt{\sqrt{I}} = \sqrt{I}$, where $\sqrt{I}$ is a radical of $I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, ideals

I want to prove $\sqrt{I}$, radical of $I$ is the smallest radical ideal containing $I$.

To show that, first I need to show $\sqrt{\sqrt{I}} = \sqrt{I}$ where $\sqrt{I} = \{ f \in R | f^n \in I, n>0\}$ is radical of $I$.

---

Following are my trial

$\Rightarrow$ Let $x \in \sqrt{\sqrt{I}}$ then $\exists m>0$ such that $x^m \in \sqrt{I}$ and then $\exists n$ such that $(x^m)^n \in I$. Let $k=mn$ then $x^k \in I$ hence $x \in \sqrt{I}$.

$\Leftarrow$ Let $x \in \sqrt{I}$, then $\exists k>0$ such that $x^k \in I$. Let $k=m n$ then $(x^m)^n \in I$. Since $x \in \sqrt{I}$ and $x^m \in \sqrt{I}$. (Since $(x^m)^n \in I$, and hence $x \in \sqrt{\sqrt{I}}$.

Is my proof correct? is there any other way to showing this?

Comment: Please use the `solution-verification` tag when you are asking people to review your proposed solution.

Comment: In the $\implies$ direction you should note that $n\gt 0$ and that therefore $k\gt 0$. In the $\Leftarrow$ direction, there is no reason to "factor" $k$. You know $x^k\in I\subseteq \sqrt{I}$, so  $x\in\sqrt{I}$. The reason why $I\subseteq \sqrt{I}$ is because $1$ is greater than $0$.

Comment: (since $I\subseteq\sqrt{I}$ for any ideal it follows that $\sqrt{I}\subseteq\sqrt{\sqrt{I}}$, assuming you know that $\sqrt{I}$ is an ideal)